# Trouble starting Django project w/o errors

Tags: django, project

This is the original code in urls.py.  Similarly, errors in view.py, and the app url.py files automatically appear whenever I start a project in django (3.2.8).  I've just begun coding, no one I've asked can answer why.  HELP!

from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

Comment: Try to ask with more structured subject. Show your code first, the issue you got and what you expect as result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.